# How to replace an asterisk with an escaped asterisk in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a school assignment where I have to write a script which will find all files in a specified directory (and all its subdirectories) that contain their names within themselves. That's all easy enough, but I've encountered a problem. There is a file called simply `'*'`. I'm using `find` to find all the files in the specified directory and when it finds this file, it gets all messed up and prints all of the files three times. So I thought I could fix the problem by escaping the `*` character in the `find` output, but I can't do it. Let's say the `find` outputs `tests/*` and I need to change it to `tests/\*`. Here's what I've tried:

`sed 's/\*/\\\*/g'`

`awk '{gsub("\*", \\\*); print} '`

Neither of these worked. The output is still `tests/*`. I've tried all possible combinations of backslashes and asterisks, even tried using single quotes somehow but I just can't make it work. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

EDIT: To further clarify, here's what my situation looks like. I have a directory called `tests` which contains files `'*'`, `test` and `z7.sh`. I want to find all the files in this directory and store them in the array `files`. So I passed the directory as an argument to the script and then did:

```
IFS=$'\n'
files=($(find "$1" -type f))
echo ${files[@]}
```

This outputs the following: `tests/* tests/test tests/z7.sh tests/test tests/z7.sh tests/test tests/z7.sh` That's obviously wrong, I need the output to be `tests/* tests/test tests/z7.sh`. I thought the solution would be to escape the asterisk but I can't even do that.

Comment: Embedding escapes and/or quotes doesn't work in most situations, because the shell parses quotes and escapes before expanding variables and command substitutions (and *not* after). See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) (the same techniques protect against wildcards). And double-quote all variable and command substitutions, so they aren't subject to word splitting or wildcard expansion.

Comment: @oguzismail I will use grep on each of the array elements (meaning on each file) and find out which of the files contains its name within itself. So if a file called Mike contains a sentence "Hello my name is Mike", the grep will find it. That part I've already done and it works, I just need to fix the asterisk because I'm not getting the correct list of files because of it.

Comment: That still didn't work, the output now is ```tests/* tests/test tests/z7.sh tests/test tests/z7.sh```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the first asterisk in sed invocation as a single asterisk is a valid BRE.

```
$ echo 'tests/*' | sed 's/*/\\*/g'
tests/\*
```

And in awk, unless you enclose a regular expression between slashes, it is parsed as a string and unescaped backslashes are consumed before it is converted to an ERE.

```
$ echo 'tests/*' | awk '{gsub(/\*/, "\\*")} 1'
tests/\*
```

But, I wouldn't bother with any of this as there are better ways to accomplish the task you described. For example:

```
find "$1" -type f -exec sh -c '
for f; do
  if grep -qF -- "${f##*/}" "$f"; then
    printf '\''%s\n'\'' "$f"
  fi
done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

This a big problem when trying to have multiple elements from the output of a single command into an array: you'll be at the mercy of bash's word splitting and glob expansion.

To avoid this, you can add the elements one by one to the array:

```
# IFS='' prevents splitting filenames with spaces
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  files+=("$line")
done < <(find "$1" -type f)
```

Or, with bash 4.x+, you can use mapfile/readarray (they are synonyms, but readarray may be more expressive):

```
mapfile -t files < <(find "$1" -type f)
```

But if you really need to, you may change bash's IFS and disable glob expansion for that command:

```
# back the current IFS so we can restore it later
oldifs=$IFS
# don't split filenames with spaces
IFS=''
# disable glob expansion
set noglob
files=($(find "$1" -type f))
# restore previous state
IFS=$oldifs
set glob
```

[Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) (a static analysis tool for Bash) has a really nice page about this problem: [SC2207](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207). I'd recommend having a linter for it on your preferred editor to help with this kind of unexpected behaviour.